# In Triangle ABC , BM and CN are perpendiculars from points B and C on any line passing through A. If L is the mid-point of BC, prove that ML = NL

Tags: triangles

I found this question in my textbook and I think this question requires the use of the  mid-point theorem. I even tried proving the equality using congruence but couldn't seem to make a headway.

I am in grade 9 so this might seem like a stupid question but please try to exlain in simple terms.

Comment: It appears to me to be by no means stupid, hence +1.

Comment: Thanks a lot @MichaelHoppe , any chance you could answer it or provide some hints ?

Comment: Cool down, I'm sure some of the staff is working on it. -- BTW: what are *your* thoughts on that problem?

Comment: @MichaelHoppe My _thoughts_ ? What do you mean ?

Answer (score 2):

Let $LL' \perp MN$ with $L'$ on $MN$. Then $LL'$ is the midline in the trapezoid $BMNC$, thus $L'$ is the midpoint of $MN$.

This shows that $ML'=L'N$.

By Pytagorean theorem

$$ML^2=ML'^2+L'L^2=L'N^2+L'L^2=NL^2$$

Comment: That's *nice*! +1 for that, too.

Comment: @N.S. Sir  if you dont mind can u please explain how $LL′$ is the midline in the trapezoid $BMNC$ and $L′$ is the midpoint of $MN$.

Comment: @SNEHILSINHA For simplicity let $C'$ be the intersection of $LL'$ with $MC$ and $B'$ the intersection of $LL'$ with $BN$. Then $LC'$ is parallel to $BM$ as both are are perpendicular on $MN$. Since $L$ is the midpoint of $BC$ it follows that $LC'$ is midline in the triangle $BCM$. Therefore $C'$ is the midle of $MC$ and $B'C'$ is parallel to the bases....

Comment: @SNEHILSINHA What I prove in this comment is the well known fact that in a trapezoid, the parallel to the bases through the midpoint of a diagonal is the midline.

Comment: @N.S. thanx sir